# python program freezes when running for a few days

Tags: python, freeze

Here's the Problem:

I'm writing a python program that's purpose is to continuously collect news from RSS feeds. I want the program to collect the data for 1 week. The problem is that the program never makes it to the end of the week. Sometimes it freezes after running for several days, sometimes several hours and even just a few minutes. It always freezes, no errors. When I say freezing I mean the interpreter seems to still be running, in that I can't give it any additional commands. How can I solve this problem?

I'll post the code below. Thanks guys!!

```
from goose import Goose
from requests import get
import urllib2
import feedparser
from urllib2 import urlopen
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import datetime as dt
import time
import os
Symbols=['AAPL','T','BA','XOM','GOOG','JPM','PG','WMT']
url='http://finance.yahoo.com/rss/headline?s='

for t in xrange(7):
    AAPL=pd.DataFrame()
    AAPL['Published']=""
    AAPL['Title']=""
    AAPL['link']=""
    AAPL['ID']=""
    AAPL['News']=""

    T=pd.DataFrame()
    T['Published']=""
    T['Title']=""
    T['link']=""
    T['ID']=""
    T['News']=""

    BA=pd.DataFrame()
    BA['Published']=""
    BA['Title']=""
    BA['link']=""
    BA['ID']=""
    BA['News']=""

    XOM=pd.DataFrame()
    XOM['Published']=""
    XOM['Title']=""
    XOM['link']=""
    XOM['ID']=""
    XOM['News']=""

    GOOG=pd.DataFrame()
    GOOG['Published']=""
    GOOG['Title']=""
    GOOG['link']=""
    GOOG['ID']=""
    GOOG['News']=""

    JPM=pd.DataFrame()
    JPM['Published']=""
    JPM['Title']=""
    JPM['link']=""
    JPM['ID']=""
    JPM['News']=""

    PG=pd.DataFrame()
    PG['Published']=""
    PG['Title']=""
    PG['link']=""
    PG['ID']=""
    PG['News']=""

    WMT=pd.DataFrame()
    WMT['Published']=""
    WMT['Title']=""
    WMT['link']=""
    WMT['ID']=""
    WMT['News']=""




    DaysIDsAAPL=[]
    DaysIDsT=[]
    DaysIDsBA=[]
    DaysIDsXOM=[]
    DaysIDsGOOG=[]
    DaysIDsJPM=[]
    DaysIDsPG=[]
    DaysIDsWMT=[]



    count=0

    AAPLCount=0
    TCount=0
    BACount=0
    XOMCount=0
    GOOGCount=0
    JPMCount=0
    PGCount=0
    WMTCount=0

    date=dt.date.today()

    newpathAAPL = r'D:\News Data\AAPL\\'+str(t)
    newpathT = r'D:\News Data\T\\'+str(t)
    newpathBA = r'D:\News Data\BA\\'+str(t)
    newpathXOM = r'D:\News Data\XOM\\'+str(t)
    newpathGOOG = r'D:\News Data\GOOG\\'+str(t)
    newpathJPM = r'D:\News Data\JPM\\'+str(t)
    newpathPG = r'D:\News Data\PG\\'+str(t)
    newpathWMT = r'D:\News Data\WMT\\'+str(t)
    os.makedirs(newpathAAPL)
    os.makedirs(newpathT)
    os.makedirs(newpathBA)
    os.makedirs(newpathXOM)
    os.makedirs(newpathGOOG)
    os.makedirs(newpathJPM)
    os.makedirs(newpathPG)
    os.makedirs(newpathWMT)
    while dt.date.today()==date:
        print "Loop"
        try:
        #AAPL inner most loop
            d1=feedparser.parse(url+Symbols[0])  
            for x in xrange(len(d1['entries'])):
                if int(d1.entries[x]['id'][14:]) not in DaysIDsAAPL:
                    DaysIDsAAPL.append(int(d1.entries[x]['id'][14:]))
                    y = len(AAPL.index.tolist())
                    m=re.search(r'\*(.*)',d1.entries[x]['link'])
                    z=re.search(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp',m.group(1))
                    if type(z) is not None:
                        m=re.sub(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp', '', m.group(1))
                    AAPL.loc[y,'Title'] =d1.entries[x]['title'].encode('utf8')
                    AAPL.loc[y,'link'] =m.encode('utf8')
                    AAPL.loc[y,'Published'] =d1.entries[x]['published'].encode('utf8')
                    AAPL.loc[y,'ID'] =int(d1.entries[x]['id'][14:])
                    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
                    page = get(m,headers=hdr)
                    extractor = Goose()
                    article = extractor.extract(raw_html=page.text)
                    text = article.cleaned_text.encode('utf8')
                    if text == '':
                        try:
                            url2 = m
                            req = urllib2.Request(url2, None, hdr)
                            html2 = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
                            raw = BeautifulSoup(html2,"lxml").get_text().encode('utf8')
                            Text_file = open(newpathAAPL+r"\\"+str(AAPLCount)+".txt", "w")
                            Text_file.write(raw)
                            Text_file.close()
                            AAPL.loc[y,'News'] = AAPLCount
                            AAPLCount+=1
                            AAPL=AAPL.fillna("")
                            AAPL.to_csv(newpathAAPL+r'\Key.csv')
                        except:
                            print m
                            print "AAPL"
                    else:
                        Text_file = open(newpathAAPL+r"\\"+str(AAPLCount)+".txt", "w")
                        Text_file.write(text)
                        Text_file.close()
                        AAPL.loc[y,'News'] =AAPLCount
                        AAPLCount+=1
                        AAPL=AAPL.fillna("")
                        AAPL.to_csv(newpathAAPL+r'\Key.csv')
                    print "AAPL"

            #T inner most loop
            d2=feedparser.parse(url+Symbols[1])

            for x in xrange(len(d2['entries'])):
                if int(d2.entries[x]['id'][14:]) not in DaysIDsT:
                    DaysIDsT.append(int(d2.entries[x]['id'][14:]))
                    y = len(T.index.tolist())
                    m=re.search(r'\*(.*)',d2.entries[x]['link'])
                    z=re.search(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp',m.group(1))
                    if type(z) is not None:
                        m=re.sub(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp', '', m.group(1))
                    T.loc[y,'Title'] =d2.entries[x]['title'].encode('utf8')
                    T.loc[y,'link'] =m.encode('utf8')
                    T.loc[y,'Published'] =d2.entries[x]['published'].encode('utf8')
                    T.loc[y,'ID'] =int(d2.entries[x]['id'][14:])
                    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
                    page = get(m,headers=hdr)
                    extractor = Goose()
                    article = extractor.extract(raw_html=page.text)
                    text = article.cleaned_text.encode('utf8')
                    if text == '':
                        try:
                            url2 = m
                            req = urllib2.Request(url2, None, hdr)
                            html2 = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
                            raw = BeautifulSoup(html2,"lxml").get_text().encode('utf8')
                            Text_file = open(newpathT+r"\\"+str(TCount)+".txt", "w")
                            Text_file.write(raw)
                            Text_file.close()
                            T.loc[y,'News'] = TCount
                            TCount+=1
                            T=T.fillna("")
                            T.to_csv(newpathT+r'\Key.csv')
                        except:
                            print m
                            print "T"
                    else:
                        Text_file = open(newpathT+r"\\"+str(TCount)+".txt", "w")
                        Text_file.write(text)
                        Text_file.close()
                        T.loc[y,'News'] =TCount
                        TCount+=1
                        T=T.fillna("")
                        T.to_csv(newpathT+r'\Key.csv')
                    print "T"

            #BA inner most loop
            d3=feedparser.parse(url+Symbols[2])

            for x in xrange(len(d3['entries'])):
                if int(d3.entries[x]['id'][14:]) not in DaysIDsBA:
                    DaysIDsBA.append(int(d3.entries[x]['id'][14:]))
                    y = len(BA.index.tolist())
                    m=re.search(r'\*(.*)',d3.entries[x]['link'])
                    z=re.search(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp',m.group(1))
                    if type(z) is not None:
                        m=re.sub(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp', '', m.group(1))
                    BA.loc[y,'Title'] =d3.entries[x]['title'].encode('utf8')
                    BA.loc[y,'link'] =m.encode('utf8')
                    BA.loc[y,'Published'] =d3.entries[x]['published'].encode('utf8')
                    BA.loc[y,'ID'] =int(d3.entries[x]['id'][14:])
                    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
                    page = get(m,headers=hdr)
                    extractor = Goose()
                    article = extractor.extract(raw_html=page.text)
                    text = article.cleaned_text.encode('utf8')
                    if text == '':
                        try:
                            url2 = m
                            req = urllib2.Request(url2, None, hdr)
                            html2 = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
                            raw = BeautifulSoup(html2,"lxml").get_text().encode('utf8')
                            Text_file = open(newpathBA+r"\\"+str(BACount)+".txt", "w")
                            Text_file.write(raw)
                            Text_file.close()
                            BA.loc[y,'News'] = BACount
                            BACount+=1
                            BA=BA.fillna("")
                            BA.to_csv(newpathBA+r'\Key.csv')
                        except:
                            print m
                            print "BA"
                    else:
                        Text_file = open(newpathBA+r"\\"+str(BACount)+".txt", "w")
                        Text_file.write(text)
                        Text_file.close()
                        BA.loc[y,'News'] =BACount
                        BACount+=1
                        BA=BA.fillna("")
                        BA.to_csv(newpathBA+r'\Key.csv')
                    print "BA"

            #XOM inner most loop
            d4=feedparser.parse(url+Symbols[3])

            for x in xrange(len(d4['entries'])):
                if int(d4.entries[x]['id'][14:]) not in DaysIDsXOM:
                    DaysIDsXOM.append(int(d4.entries[x]['id'][14:]))
                    y = len(XOM.index.tolist())
                    m=re.search(r'\*(.*)',d4.entries[x]['link'])
                    z=re.search(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp',m.group(1))
                    if type(z) is not None:
                        m=re.sub(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp', '', m.group(1))
                    XOM.loc[y,'Title'] =d4.entries[x]['title'].encode('utf8')
                    XOM.loc[y,'link'] =m.encode('utf8')
                    XOM.loc[y,'Published'] =d4.entries[x]['published'].encode('utf8')
                    XOM.loc[y,'ID'] =int(d4.entries[x]['id'][14:])
                    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
                    page = get(m,headers=hdr)
                    extractor = Goose()
                    article = extractor.extract(raw_html=page.text)
                    text = article.cleaned_text.encode('utf8')
                    if text == '':
                        try:
                            url2 = m
                            req = urllib2.Request(url2, None, hdr)
                            html2 = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
                            raw = BeautifulSoup(html2,"lxml").get_text().encode('utf8')
                            Text_file = open(newpathXOM+r"\\"+str(XOMCount)+".txt", "w")
                            Text_file.write(raw)
                            Text_file.close()
                            XOM.loc[y,'News'] = XOMCount
                            XOMCount+=1
                            XOM=XOM.fillna("")
                            XOM.to_csv(newpathXOM+r'\Key.csv')
                        except:
                            print m
                            print "XOM"
                    else:
                        Text_file = open(newpathXOM+r"\\"+str(XOMCount)+".txt", "w")
                        Text_file.write(text)
                        Text_file.close()
                        XOM.loc[y,'News'] =XOMCount
                        XOMCount+=1
                        XOM=XOM.fillna("")
                        XOM.to_csv(newpathXOM+r'\Key.csv')

            #GOOG inner most loop
            d5=feedparser.parse(url+Symbols[4])

            for x in xrange(len(d5['entries'])):
                if int(d5.entries[x]['id'][14:]) not in DaysIDsGOOG:
                    DaysIDsGOOG.append(int(d5.entries[x]['id'][14:]))
                    y = len(GOOG.index.tolist())
                    m=re.search(r'\*(.*)',d5.entries[x]['link'])
                    z=re.search(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp',m.group(1))
                    if type(z) is not None:
                        m=re.sub(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp', '', m.group(1))
                    GOOG.loc[y,'Title'] =d5.entries[x]['title'].encode('utf8')
                    GOOG.loc[y,'link'] =m.encode('utf8')
                    GOOG.loc[y,'Published'] =d5.entries[x]['published'].encode('utf8')
                    GOOG.loc[y,'ID'] =int(d5.entries[x]['id'][14:])
                    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
                    page = get(m,headers=hdr)
                    extractor = Goose()
                    article = extractor.extract(raw_html=page.text)
                    text = article.cleaned_text.encode('utf8')
                    if text == '':
                        try:
                            url2 = m
                            req = urllib2.Request(url2, None, hdr)
                            html2 = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
                            raw = BeautifulSoup(html2,"lxml").get_text().encode('utf8')
                            Text_file = open(newpathGOOG+r"\\"+str(GOOGCount)+".txt", "w")
                            Text_file.write(raw)
                            Text_file.close()
                            GOOG.loc[y,'News'] = GOOGCount
                            GOOGCount+=1
                            GOOG=GOOG.fillna("")
                            GOOG.to_csv(newpathGOOG+r'\Key.csv')
                        except:
                            print m
                            print "GOOG"
                    else:
                        Text_file = open(newpathGOOG+r"\\"+str(GOOGCount)+".txt", "w")
                        Text_file.write(text)
                        Text_file.close()
                        GOOG.loc[y,'News'] =GOOGCount
                        GOOGCount+=1
                        GOOG=GOOG.fillna("")
                        GOOG.to_csv(newpathGOOG+r'\Key.csv')
                    print "GOOG"

            #JPM inner most loop
            d6=feedparser.parse(url+Symbols[5])

            for x in xrange(len(d6['entries'])):
                if int(d6.entries[x]['id'][14:]) not in DaysIDsJPM:
                    DaysIDsJPM.append(int(d6.entries[x]['id'][14:]))
                    y = len(JPM.index.tolist())
                    m=re.search(r'\*(.*)',d6.entries[x]['link'])
                    z=re.search(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp',m.group(1))
                    if type(z) is not None:
                        m=re.sub(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp', '', m.group(1))
                    JPM.loc[y,'Title'] =d6.entries[x]['title'].encode('utf8')
                    JPM.loc[y,'link'] =m.encode('utf8')
                    JPM.loc[y,'Published'] =d6.entries[x]['published'].encode('utf8')
                    JPM.loc[y,'ID'] =int(d6.entries[x]['id'][14:])
                    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
                    page = get(m,headers=hdr)
                    extractor = Goose()
                    article = extractor.extract(raw_html=page.text)
                    text = article.cleaned_text.encode('utf8')
                    if text == '':
                        try:
                            url2 = m
                            req = urllib2.Request(url2, None, hdr)
                            html2 = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
                            raw = BeautifulSoup(html2,"lxml").get_text().encode('utf8')
                            Text_file = open(newpathJPM+r"\\"+str(JPMCount)+".txt", "w")
                            Text_file.write(raw)
                            Text_file.close()
                            JPM.loc[y,'News'] = JPMCount
                            JPMCount+=1
                            JPM=JPM.fillna("")
                            JPM.to_csv(newpathJPM+r'\Key.csv')
                        except:
                            print m
                            print "JPM"
                    else:
                        Text_file = open(newpathJPM+r"\\"+str(JPMCount)+".txt", "w")
                        Text_file.write(text)
                        Text_file.close()
                        JPM.loc[y,'News'] =JPMCount
                        JPMCount+=1
                        JPM=JPM.fillna("")
                        JPM.to_csv(newpathJPM+r'\Key.csv')
                    print "JPM"


            #PG inner most loop
            d7=feedparser.parse(url+Symbols[6])

            for x in xrange(len(d7['entries'])):
                if int(d7.entries[x]['id'][14:]) not in DaysIDsPG:
                    DaysIDsPG.append(int(d7.entries[x]['id'][14:]))
                    y = len(PG.index.tolist())
                    m=re.search(r'\*(.*)',d7.entries[x]['link'])
                    z=re.search(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp',m.group(1))
                    if type(z) is not None:
                        m=re.sub(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp', '', m.group(1))
                    PG.loc[y,'Title'] =d7.entries[x]['title'].encode('utf8')
                    PG.loc[y,'link'] =m.encode('utf8')
                    PG.loc[y,'Published'] =d7.entries[x]['published'].encode('utf8')
                    PG.loc[y,'ID'] =int(d7.entries[x]['id'][14:])
                    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
                    page = get(m,headers=hdr)
                    extractor = Goose()
                    article = extractor.extract(raw_html=page.text)
                    text = article.cleaned_text.encode('utf8')
                    if text == "":
                        try:
                            url2 = m
                            req = urllib2.Request(url2, None, hdr)
                            html2 = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
                            raw = BeautifulSoup(html2,"lxml").get_text().encode('utf8')
                            Text_file = open(newpathPG+r"\\"+str(PGCount)+".txt", "w")
                            Text_file.write(raw)
                            Text_file.close()
                            PG.loc[y,'News'] = PGCount
                            PGCount+=1
                            PG=PG.fillna("")
                            PG.to_csv(newpathPG+r'\Key.csv')
                        except:
                            print m
                            print "PG"
                    else:
                        Text_file = open(newpathPG+r"\\"+str(PGCount)+".txt", "w")
                        Text_file.write(text)
                        Text_file.close()
                        PG.loc[y,'News'] =PGCount
                        PGCount+=1
                        PG=PG.fillna("")
                        PG.to_csv(newpathPG+r'\Key.csv')
                    print "PG"


            #WMT inner most loop
            d8=feedparser.parse(url+Symbols[7])

            for x in xrange(len(d8['entries'])):
                if int(d8.entries[x]['id'][14:]) not in DaysIDsWMT:
                    DaysIDsWMT.append(int(d8.entries[x]['id'][14:]))
                    y = len(WMT.index.tolist())
                    m=re.search(r'\*(.*)',d8.entries[x]['link'])
                    z=re.search(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp',m.group(1))
                    if type(z) is not None:
                        m=re.sub(r'\?ru=yahoo\?mod=yahoo_itp', '', m.group(1))
                    WMT.loc[y,'Title'] =d8.entries[x]['title'].encode('utf8')
                    WMT.loc[y,'link'] =m.encode('utf8')
                    WMT.loc[y,'Published'] =d8.entries[x]['published'].encode('utf8')
                    WMT.loc[y,'ID'] =int(d8.entries[x]['id'][14:])
                    hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
                    page = get(m,headers=hdr)
                    extractor = Goose()
                    article = extractor.extract(raw_html=page.text)
                    text = article.cleaned_text.encode('utf8')
                    if text == "":
                        try:
                            url2 = m
                            req = urllib2.Request(url2, None, hdr)
                            html2 = urlopen(req).read().decode('utf8')
                            raw = BeautifulSoup(html2,"lxml").get_text().encode('utf8')
                            Text_file = open(newpathWMT+r"\\"+str(WMTCount)+".txt", "w")
                            Text_file.write(raw)
                            Text_file.close()
                            WMT.loc[y,'News'] = WMTCount
                            WMTCount+=1
                            WMT=WMT.fillna("")
                            WMT.to_csv(newpathWMT+r'\Key.csv')
                        except:
                            print m
                            print "WMT"
                    else:
                        Text_file = open(newpathWMT+r"\\"+str(WMTCount)+".txt", "w")
                        Text_file.write(text)
                        Text_file.close()
                        WMT.loc[y,'News'] =WMTCount
                        WMTCount+=1
                        WMT=WMT.fillna("")
                        WMT.to_csv(newpathWMT+r'\Key.csv')
                    print "WMT"       
            count+=1
            print count
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            print "Error"
    AAPL=AAPL.fillna("")
    AAPL.to_csv(newpathAAPL+r'\Key.csv')
    T=T.fillna("")
    T.to_csv(newpathT+r'\Key.csv')
    BA=BA.fillna("")
    BA.to_csv(newpathBA+r'\Key.csv')
    XOM=XOM.fillna("")
    XOM.to_csv(newpathXOM+r'\Key.csv')
    GOOG=GOOG.fillna("")
    GOOG.to_csv(newpathGOOG+r'\Key.csv')
    JPM=JPM.fillna("")
    JPM.to_csv(newpathJPM+r'\Key.csv')
    PG=PG.fillna("")
    PG.to_csv(newpathPG+r'\Key.csv')
    WMT=WMT.fillna("")
    WMT.to_csv(newpathWMT+r'\Key.csv')
```

Comment: You have a lot of duplicated code; you can extract the rudundant code into helper methods (small functions) that you can pass in arguments

Comment: if your code have no bug, try to disable gc and manually collect the garbage (if you are using 2.6).

Comment: Maybe try to break down the code to be able to isolate problem. Separate all those sections in different functions and add a decorator responsible for tracing, e.g. `timestamp - func name started - parameters` and `timestamp - func name ended - duration`. There could be an issue with the service you are calling that you are not handling gracefully, but it's hard to tell in a 500 line program!

Comment: Hey guys,

thanks for the suggestions, I'll try them out and report back with what happens. Sorry about the messiness of the code, I know there's a ton of redundancy in there, I was going more for time than cleanliness. Clearly a bad in hind sight, lol

Answer (score 1):

in the program is consumed too much RAM when  it collects a too large of feeds or if there are other active processes on your system (this is why the time to freeze differs), see [Why does a simple python script crash my system](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2060615)

The process in that your program runs stores the arrays and variables for the calculations in *process memory* which is ram

you can fix this by forcing the program to use hard disk memory.

For workarounds (`shelve`, **periodically saving the collected feeds to a textfile** (moves information from ram to rom and frees ram), ...) see the following links

[memory usage, how to free memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781741/memory-usage-how-to-free-memory)

[Python large variable RAM usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670005/python-large-variable-ram-usage)

[I need to free up RAM by storing a Python dictionary on the hard drive, not in RAM. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392663/i-need-to-free-up-ram-by-storing-a-python-dictionary-on-the-hard-drive-not-in-r)