# Why does running this script freeze my computer?

Tags: python, scipy, freeze, fftpack

I wrote a script in Python using SciPy to perform a short-time Fourier transform on a signal. When I ran it on a signal with a thousand timepoints, it ran fine. When I ran it on a signal with a million timepoints, it froze my computer (computer doesn't respond, and if audio was playing, the computer outputs a skipping and looping buzz); this has consistently occurred all three times I attempted it. I've written scripts that would take hours, but I've never encountered one that actually froze my computer. Any idea why? The script is posted below:

```
import scipy as sp
from scipy import fftpack

def STFT(signal, seconds_per_sample, window_seconds, min_Hz):
    window_samples = int(window_seconds/seconds_per_sample) + 1
    signal_samples = len(signal)
    if signal_samples <= window_samples:
        length = max(signal_samples, int(1/(seconds_per_sample*min_Hz)) + 1)
        return sp.array([0]), fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fftfreq(length, seconds_per_sample)), fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft(signal, n = length))
    else:
        length = max(window_samples, int(1/(seconds_per_sample*min_Hz)) + 1)
        frequency = fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fftfreq(length, seconds_per_sample))
        time = []
        FTs = []
        for i in range(signal_samples - window_samples):
            time.append(seconds_per_sample*i)
            FTs.append(fftpack.fftshift(fftpack.fft(signal[i:i + window_samples], n = length)))
        return sp.array(time), frequency, sp.array(FTs)
```

Comment: Did you look on the memory consumption of the script? If it does heavy allocation, it could have these consequences.

Comment: So it's an issue of the main memory being exhausted?

Comment: The resulting sp.array(FTs) would contain on the order of 10^12 floats, after all.

Comment: I don't know, but it may well be. Look at some OS statistics when the script runs and you should see.

Comment: Seems like that's the issue. My computer has ~12 GB of RAM, and 10^12 float64s would take up at least 8 TB.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

in the script is consumed too much RAM when you run it over a too large number of points, see [Why does a simple python script crash my system](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2060615)

The process in that your program runs stores the arrays and variables for the calculations in *process memory* which is ram

you can fix this by forcing the program to use hard disk memory.

For workarounds (`shelve`,...) see the following links

[memory usage, how to free memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10781741/memory-usage-how-to-free-memory)

[Python large variable RAM usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2670005/python-large-variable-ram-usage)

[I need to free up RAM by storing a Python dictionary on the hard drive, not in RAM. Is it possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392663/i-need-to-free-up-ram-by-storing-a-python-dictionary-on-the-hard-drive-not-in-r)

Comment: I guess I can write the output iteratively to a .txt file or something. Any idea how to make a 3D plot iteratively, lol.